# Number comparison to find max/min in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. I have written a simple program to find greatest of 3 numbers. I get the right answer when I give input numbers having same number of digits (Eg. 50 80 20). However when I give input (50 130 20) it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
num1=input("Enter 3 numbers\n")
num2=input()
num3=input()
if(num1 > num2):
    if(num1 > num3):
        print("The greatest number is "+ str(num1))
    else:
        print("the greatest number is "+ str(num3))
else:
    if(num2 > num3):
        print("The greatest number is " + str(num2))
    else:
        print("The greatest number is " + str(num3))
```

Comment: These are strings not numbers. wrap your inputs with `int(input())`, strings compare differently than numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are yet another victim of dynamic typing.**

When you read in data to your `num` variables, the variables are treated as strings.

When Python compares two strings using the `<` or `>` operator, it does so lexicographically -- meaning alphabetically. Here's a few examples.

```
'apple' < 'orange' //true
'apple' < 'adam' //false
'6' < '7' //true as expected
'80' < '700' //returns false, as 8 > 7 lexiographically
```

Therefore, you want to convert your input using `int()`, so `<` comparisons work as expected.

**Code**

```
num1=int("Enter 3 numbers\n")
num2=int(input())
num3=int(input())
if(num1 > num2):
    if(num1 > num3):
        print("The greatest number is "+ str(num1))
    else:
        print("the greatest number is "+ str(num3))
else:
    if(num2 > num3):
        print("The greatest number is " + str(num2))
    else:
        print("The greatest number is " + str(num3))
```

Comment: The OP's problem is not in converting to a string (which is perfectly justified), but in *not* converting to an `int`. Your code will raise an exception: one cannot add strings and numbers.

Comment: The OP _does not_ convert to a string. Function `input()` already returns a string. On the other hand, in your code, you attempt to add `"The greatest number is "` (a string) and `int(num1)` (a number), which is impossible.

Comment: Totally messed up how I "fixed" his code. Answer is edited. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the maximum of any number of numbers with [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

```
print "The greatest number is " + max(int(num1), int(num2), int(num3))
```

Comment: Yes but i am trying to solve it without the max() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want TimTom's (no max()), here is another way:

```
num1= int("Enter 3 Number\n")
num2= int(input())
num3= int(input())

if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
   numLarge = num1
#  print exchange
elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
   numLarge = num2
#  print exchange
else:
   numLarge = num3
#  print exchange

print("The greatest is " + str(numLarge))
```